# Skip struct field when serializing

Tags: rust, serde

Given the struct:

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct ReqMetrics {
    start: Timespec,
    pub name: String
}
```

How can I ensure that Serde ignores the field `start` when serializing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct annotation is [`#[serde(skip_serializing)]`](https://serde.rs/attributes.html#field-attributes).